# About accessing structs defined in different source file

Tags: c, struct

Not any homework, but seem to have got lost while doing basics, hence asking.

Say I have 2 C source files. 1.c & 2.c

2.c is as follows:

```
typedef struct mystr_
{
    int a;
    float b;
}mystr;

void fun()
{
    mystr q;

    some code....
}
```

And 1.c is as below:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void fun();


main()
{
    //How to access / declare a variable of type mystr here.

    mystr *v1;//This obviously gives compiler errors

      some code....    

}
```

How to access the structure mystr defined in 2.c from file 1.c to have variables of that struct type there?

EDIT:

Sorry forgot to mention in OP. I cannot move the declaration out in a header file for some reason --> It is a quick hack that I am trying to check in a existing code. Then is there any way to access it directly from the other source file?

Comment: Define `mystr` in a header file and include it in both C files.

Comment: There are no ways to access it from other source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use headers.

Create a file `2.h`

```
typedef struct mystr_
{
    int a;
    float b;
}mystr;
```

And include it in `1.c`

```
#include "2.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void void fun();
```

EDIT:
Because you are not able to extract the declaration into a header file and include it, there is no other way than copying the declaration. This is a highly fragile construct, quick but mainly dirty and not really recommended unless you are out of other options.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention in OP. I cannot move the declaration out in a header file for some reason --> It is a quick hack that I am trying to check in a existing code. Then is there any way to access it directly from the other source file?

Comment: You can always copy & paste :-)

Comment: Thanks. Copy pasted the structure definition in 1.c and i can create vars of that type. Was not sure if it was re-declaration or re-definition of structure mystr? It seems re-declaration obviously as it worked w/o re-definition errors.

Comment: Can you add your comment - 'Copy the declaration in the needed source file' in your answer. I want to accept it. As it is just another valid solution to this problem.(May be not ideal but works!)

Comment: It isn't exactly a redeclaration, as it is parsed only once. It is a new declaration which happens to exactly match the declaration in an other file. A highly fragile construct, quick but mainly dirty.